# Error while shuffling an Array in Java

Tags: java, swap, shuffle, xor

This is what I have so far

```
int[] question = new int[25];

for (int i = 0; i < question.length; i++){
    question[i] = i+1;
}

Random rand = new Random();

int max = question.length-1, min = 1;

for(int i = 0; i < question.length; i++){
    int idx = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
    randg[i] = idx;
    question[i] ^= question[idx];
    question[idx] ^= question[i];
    question[i] ^= question[idx];

    if(question[i] == 0){
        System.out.println("Something went wrong!" + i + " " + idx);
    }
}
```

So the problem seems to be when the rand value (idx) is equal to i, for the swap... it just replaces the value with 0.

How do I fix that problem?

Comment: If you are unable to tell what the effect of the error is, then it is difficult to help.

Comment: I know what the problem is... I just don't know how to fix it.

Comment: The problem is when it swaps idx values that equal i values. It sets that value to zero.

Comment: For swapping you need a help variable wich you dont have+

Comment: No exceptions, it originally sets the array with values from 1 to 25, but after the shuffle, it inserts 0's in for some values, where idx==i for the swap

Comment: Yes the most basic programming technic is to correctly swap two values. you need a help variable to store one of the values to swap

Comment: @AlexWien [XOR Swap Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm)

Comment: @AlexWien for a XOR swap, you actually don't need a helper value

Comment: Ah that idiots: read Effective Java Second Edition: Rule: "Don't be to clever", dont use the XOR swap. This is outdated since more than 30 years now. (Although it works)

Comment: @AlexWien [Write Dumb Code](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/devinsight-1-139780.html).

Comment: Xor swap may zero out the bits when using the same variable as argument: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/182037/is-this-xor-value-swap-algorithm-still-in-use-or-useful

Comment: @ElliottFrisch , Yes it is not in the book of Bloch (Effective Java, except Item 55 is near)

Comment: finally found your problem: The xor swap does not work for same arguments: see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quickest fix I know; use an `Integer[]`, [`Arrays.asList(T...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) and [`Collections.shuffle(List)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29) like

```
Integer[] question = new Integer[25];
for (int i = 0; i < question.length; i++) {
    question[i] = i + 1;
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(question));
Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(question));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(question));
```

Or, with your code you could add

```
for(int i = 0; i < question.length; i++){
  int idx = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
  if (idx == i) {
    i--; 
    continue;
  }
```

Comment: I need the method to return an `int[]`

Comment: @Arian you could copy it to an `int[]`

Comment: But this does not answer why he gets an 0.

Answer (score 1):

The XOR swap you are using is not recommended, it may zero out the bits,
when you pass the same variable twice, so swap(a,a) might deliver 0:
For furthe info see: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/182037/is-this-xor-value-swap-algorithm-still-in-use-or-useful

You gain nothing with the XOR Swap, it's neither clever, nor faster.
It's a trick from assembly langugae to save one variable.

The recommended way to swap:

swapping two values in array a[] at index i and j: : a[i] and a[j]:

```
int help = a[i];
a[i] = a[j];
a[j] = help;
```

Comment: OP is using a xor swap algorithm which does not need a temporary.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch XOR swap may zero out the bits if using the same argument (http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/182037/is-this-xor-value-swap-algorithm-still-in-use-or-useful